# departure format in R

Tags: r, here-api

I am trying to get historical traffic data from here api. I m not sure of I have the correct departure format in R to be able to retrieve the data. I want traffic data for california but I live in a different state.

```html
call <- paste0("https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json",
               "?app_id=","",
               "&app_code=","",
               "&waypoint0=geo!",34.13336,",",-117.416456,
               "&waypoint1=geo!",33.727436,",",-117.784915,
              "&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled;",
               "&departure=","2018-12-13T03:58:00-07")
              



  #Testing URL Connection
GET(call)


response <-fromJSON(call, simplify = FALSE )
str(response)


  
#}
# parse response and get transit time
travel_time <- response[[1]]$route[[1]]$summary$travelTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague. Lets answer it this way:

Yes, the time format is right. If you choose a departure time in the morning where you can expect a bit more traffic e.g.

https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx&waypoint0=geo!34.13336,-117.416456&waypoint1=geo!33.727436,-117.784915&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled;&departure=2018-12-14T09:58:00-07

You will also retrieve a longer travel time:

```
"summary": {
        "distance": 73128,
        "trafficTime": 3974,
        "baseTime": 3737,
        "flags": ["tollroad", "noThroughRoad", "motorway", "builtUpArea", "privateRoad"],
        "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">73.1 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">1:06 h</span>.",
        "travelTime": 3974,
        "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
      }
```

One general comment, **please do NOT post your credentials within any forums**. Just add some place holder in the future.